# Error when trying to run Avalonia through DRM in raspberry pi 4

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi4, avalonia

I can't run an Avalonia Application in my Raspberry Pi 4 using Raspberry Os Lite and DRM, I followed all the instructions in this tutorial:
https://docs.avaloniaui.net/guides/deep-dives/running-on-raspbian-lite-via-drm

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (95): drmModeGetResources failed
   at Avalonia.LinuxFramebuffer.Output.DrmResources..ctor(Int32 fd) in /_/src/Linux/Avalonia.LinuxFramebuffer/Output/DrmBindings.cs:line 89
   at Avalonia.LinuxFramebuffer.Output.DrmOutput..ctor(String path) in /_/src/Linux/Avalonia.LinuxFramebuffer/Output/DrmOutput.cs:line 30
   at LinuxFramebufferPlatformExtensions.StartLinuxDrm[T](T builder, String[] args, String card, Double scaling) in /_/src/Linux/Avalonia.LinuxFramebuffer/LinuxFramebufferPlatform.cs:line 142
```

This is my MainWindow.axaml

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:LeanovationHitachi="clr-namespace:LeanovationHitachi"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="480"
        x:Class="LeanovationHitachi.MainWindow"
        HasSystemDecorations="false"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Width="800"
        Height="480"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="LeanovationHitachi">
    <LeanovationHitachi:MainView/>
</Window>
```

This is my MainSingleView.axaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:LeanovationHitachi="clr-namespace:LeanovationHitachi"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="LeanovationHitachi.MainSingleView">
    <LeanovationHitachi:MainView/>
</UserControl>
```

This is my MainView.axaml

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia;assembly=Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="LeanovationHitachi.MainView"
             Width="800"
             Height="480">
    <Border>
//All my code
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

This is my Program.cs

```
using Avalonia;
using Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia;
using Projektanker.Icons.Avalonia.FontAwesome;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
namespace LeanovationHitachi;

class Program
{
    // Initialization code. Don't use any Avalonia, third-party APIs or any
    // SynchronizationContext-reliant code before AppMain is called: things aren't initialized
    // yet and stuff might break.
    [STAThread]
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = BuildAvaloniaApp();
        if (args.Contains("--drm"))
        {
            SilenceConsole();
            return builder.StartLinuxDrm(args);
        }

        return builder.StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);
    }

    private static void SilenceConsole()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            while (true)
                Console.ReadKey(true);
        })
        { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }

    // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    {
        return AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .LogToTrace()
            .WithIcons(container => container
                .Register<FontAwesomeIconProvider>());
    }
}
```

App.axaml.cs

```
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls.ApplicationLifetimes;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

namespace LeanovationHitachi;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
            desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        else if (ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime singleView)
            singleView.MainView = new MainSingleView();

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable the VC4 V3D driver. Use nano or attach your SD card to your computer and find the `config.txt` file in the boot partition.

```
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

And do not forget to run your app with --drm

```
./LeanovationHitachi --drm
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding all parameters to the method call:

```
if (args.Contains("--drm"))
{
    SilenceConsole();
    return builder.StartLinuxDrm(args: args, card: "/dev/dri/card1", scaling: 1.0);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34482499)